# How to get a specific field of list of objects in an array of strings

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, list, arrays

I have a list of persons like this :

```
foreach (GridViewRow r in gv_contactList.Rows)
                        {
                            Person p = new Person();
                            p.Id = int.Parse(gv_contactList.DataKeys[r.RowIndex].Value.ToString());
                            p.Name = r.Cells[1].Text.TrimEnd();
                            p.Mobile = r.Cells[2].Text.TrimEnd();
                            p.Email = r.Cells[3].Text.TrimEnd();
                            p.Pkind = 1;//ToDo
                            plst.Add(p);

                        }
```

How to get an array of mobile numbers in `string[]`
in the same previous loop where the mobile number is not null or empty .
instead of looping again through the list of persons to put the mobile numbers in the array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really sure what you want. But if you want an array of string phone numbers from your Person List `plst` you can do:

```
string[] phoneArray = plist
                          .Where(r=>string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(r.Mobile))
                          .Select(r=>r.Mobile.ToString())
                          .ToArray();
```

Comment: Can't convert `Person[]` to `string[]`

Comment: @just_name, my bad, forgot the Select Statement, you may remove .ToString if `Mobile` is already of type string

Answer (score 2):

```
var mobiles = new List<string>();

foreach (GridViewRow r in gv_contactList.Rows) 
{ 
    ...
    p.Mobile = r.Cells[2].Text.TrimEnd(); 
    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(p.Mobile)) {
        mobiles.Add(p.Mobile);
    }
    ... 
} 

var mobilesArray = mobiles.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Declare an `ArrayList` before `foreach`:

```
ArrayList<String> mobNums = new ArrayList<String>();
```

within `foreach` add the mobile no. to it:

```
mobNums.Add(p.Mobile);
```

After `foreach` change it to Array:

```
String[] arr = mobNums.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `plst` is already existing:

```
var plst = ...

var persons = from GridViewRow r in gv_contactList.Rows
              select new Person {
                Id = int.Parse(gv_contactList.DataKeys[r.RowIndex].Value.ToString()),
                Name = r.Cells[1].Text.TrimEnd(),
                Mobile = r.Cells[2].Text.TrimEnd(),
                Email = r.Cells[3].Text.TrimEnd(),
                Pkind = 1,
              };

var mobiles = persons.Aggregate(new List<string>(), (acc, cur) => 
              {
                plst.Add(cur);

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cur.Mobile))
                    acc.Add(cur.Mobile);
                return acc;
              }).ToArray();
```

The enumeration happens just once.